# is Solr a good solution for my case

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, solr

I'm trying to code a ws that will provide me with data to update my mobile application content, I was asked to get this information from Apache Solr unstead of the actual MySQL database, in order to do that i'll need to import my MySQL database to Solr (I'm still woundering how to do so, with nested entities or create a core for each single entity) and each time I call the update WS it should create a huge JSON with all the data imported since the last timestamp (the mobile will send the last "succesfull update" timestamp with each update request).

my questions are : 
 1. Is Solr a good solution for this use case or not ?
 2. How should the solr schema.xml import the database ? with nested entities or what ?

Thank you a lot for your help :)

Comment: There isn't really enough information on your use case to respond.  SOLR is very good at indexing large numbers of slow moving, flat-structured documents for searching with complex queries (free-text, faceting, spacial, etc).  It's not well suited to multiple layers or relational data, and may be overkill for small data-sets or searches that a relational database is already good at performing.

Comment: Thanks for helping, 
in my use case I'm asked to import a fully relational database (16 tables) to Solr, in order to make a webservice that take a timestamp as a parameter and returns all the records (with a "created_at" value > to the given timestamp) from each entity, and return it as a json to the mobile app.

Comment: It sounds like it could be flattened, and that it might be a fair enough use-case.  I'd avoid nested entities unless you have a reason to implement them, but basically design a schema that covers your use-case bearing in mind it should be flat, and just try it - see what you think.

Comment: By flat you mean a core for each entity ? 
I've never used Solr Before so I'm actually lost right now.

Comment: Maybe a core per entity (though probably not), maybe a single core that includes all the attributes of all entities, maybe a single core that includes only the attributes you actually care about for searching as attributes, with a single 'content' representation of what you need to return / display but not search on, maybe a fuller relational style index with nested entities as you initially describe.  TBO, the answer is probably beyond SO discussion. Unfortunately your best bet is probably to read a lot on the topic and go ahead and try things.